# Prove $\inf(-x) = -\sup(x)$

Tags: proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Suppose S is bounded above, Prove $\inf(-x) = -\sup(x)$

I've reckon there are similar proofs here with negative signs in different ways, but I want to get some proof verification as well as some improvement if needs to be.

what i have done so far is:

Let $\sup(x) = B$ that allows us to say $B \le y$ for all $y \in S$

Thus we know that $-B \le -y$ for all $y \in -S$

Thus we know that $-B$ is a lower bound of $x$ and there exists $b \le -y$ that $y \le -b$ for all $y \in S$

hence $y \le B$, $-B \le - y$, $-B=-\sup(x) \le -y = \inf(-x)$

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is $x$ a set? I think you mean $\inf_{x \in S}(-x)$ in the first line and, later, $y \in S$ instead of $y \in x$?

Comment: @gerw oh yes.. you are right, i've messed up all the y,xs..

Comment: There are numerous snags ("$x$" instead of "$S$" in the problem statement and elsewhere; inequality signs going the wrong way, "$y \in -S$" instead of "$y \in S$", ...), but the main structural gap is you need to show that because $B$ is the _least_ upper bound of $S$, $-B$ is the _greatest_ lower bound of $-S$. To do that you'll a formalization of _least_, possibly of the form "For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists [...] such that [...]."